# Export collection to individual images in GEE

Tags: export, google-earth-engine

I want to clip a MODIS image collection to an area defined by a bounding box in Google Earth Engine and then export the images separately to my google drive. I want to use a map function to avoid for loop, but the export module parameters can not be dynamically set. For example, for the description (that would be the file name), I want it to be equal to the id of each individual image. However, export module expect a string for name and can not accept a computed object. getInfo() also doesn't work in mapped functions.

```
var imageCol = MODIS.select('LST_Day_1km').filterDate(startDate, endDate);
var clippedCol = imageCol.map(function(image){   
    var clipped = image.clip(Bbox);   
    Export.image.toAsset({
       image: clipped,
       description: image.metadata('system:index'),
       region: Bbox,
       scale: 1000
    });   
    return clipped   });
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a duplicate, but an answer with less code lines is:

```js
// load tools from Fito Principe
var tools = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:tools');

// add col2drive function
var exportfunction = tools.col2drive;

// export collection to google drive
exportfunction(coll,'coll_name',{other parameters});
```

Part of a set of useful functions from [Rodrigo E. Principe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23470/rodrigo-e-principe).